# Integrating ANTLR4 into Java

Tags: java, antlr4

I have generated and compiled a grammar with ANTLR4. VIA the command line I am able to see if there is an error, but I am having issues integrating this parser into a java program successfully. I am able to use ANTLR4 methods as I've added the JAR's to my library in Eclipse, however I am completely unable to retrieve token text or find out if an error is being generated in any sort of meaningful manner. Any help would be appreciated. If I'm being ambiguous by any means, please let me know and I'll delve into more detail.

Looking at previous versions, an equivalent method to something like compilationUnit() might be what I want.

Comment: Have you considered using parboiled?

Comment: I ended up just writing the parser from scratch unfortunately. It wasn't the most troublesome task, as my grammar wasn't terribly complex. However I feel silly after wasting roughly three hours trying to get antlr to work and just doing it myself like I had planned from the get go.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (assuming you generated `GeneratedLexer` and `GeneratedParser` from your grammar):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import test.GeneratedLexer;
import test.GeneratedParser;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputFile = null;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            inputFile = args[0];
        }
        InputStream is = System.in;
        if (inputFile != null) {
            is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        }
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(is);
        GeneratedLexer lexer = new GeneratedLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        GeneratedParser parser = new GeneratedParser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.startRule();

        // Do something useful with the tree (e.g. use a visitor if you generated one)
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
    }
}
```

You could also use a [parser and lexer interpreter](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+and+lexer+interpreters) if you don't want to pregenerate them from your grammar (or you have a dynamic grammar).